# Find all span elements whose text does not contain a string

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find all `<span/>` elements which belongs to a specific class whose `text()` value does not contain part of a string.

This is what I've attempted so far:

```
if ($("#details .error").not($(this).text().contains("This schedule is used")).length == 0) {
    //do something
}
else {
    //do something else   
}
```

But I get a `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` error.
Any help please?

Comment: there is no `this` in a if

Comment: does the `span` elements contains the `error` class?

Comment: may be `$("#details .error").not(":has(:contains(This schedule is used))").length` - but won't be able to provide a complete answer without seeing your html

Comment: Yes, the `span` element contains the `error` class

Comment: can you give a sample of the html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : You need not to use `$(this)`, instead use `contains()` and `not()` in selectors

```
if ($("#details .error:not(:contains(This schedule is used))").length == 0) {
    //do something
}
else {
    //do something else   
}
```

Or you can do the same using `filter()`

```
// get all span not having text specified
   var span = $("#details .error").filter(function(){
                  return $(this).text().indexOf('This schedule is used')==-1;
              });

   //check length of span
   if (span.length == 0) {
        //do something
    }
    else {
        //do something else   
    }
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks Bhushan, will tick answered as soon as the timelimit has passed.

Comment: @RudolfLamprecht Nice use of `filter()`! I didn't though about that one. But why `indexOf` and not `$.contains`?

Comment: @AndreasFurster, yeah we can use `.contains` also but just thought of `indexOf` as another option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `this` in a if 'scope', so use the selector again

```
if ($("#details .error").not($("#details .error").text().contains("This schedule is used")).length == 0) {
    //do something
}
else {
    //do something else   
}
```